# What happened when `pop`-ing an element while `for` looping a list

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, for-loop

Code:

```
arr = [ i for i in xrange(10) ]

for i in arr:
  if i in arr:
    print i
    arr.pop(0)

print arr
```

And the output:

```
$ python2.7 ts.py 
0
2
4
6
8
[5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Why is this the result? Shouldn't it be `[]`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Updating a Sequence while Iterating has some unexpected results, which is why it is never recommended. The following graphic depicts how the variable `i` changes every time you iterate while popping from the list

```
var    Instruction                    <--------- arr -------------> 
 i                                   [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
 |     for i in arr                   ^
 |____________________________________|
 |                                    |
 |                                    V
 |     arr.pop(0)                    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
 |     
 |     for i in arr                  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
 |                                       ^
 |_______________________________________|
 |_______________________________________|
 |                                       |
 |                                       V
 |     arr.pop(0)                    [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
 |     
 |     for i in arr                  [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
 |                                          ^
 |__________________________________________|
 |__________________________________________|
 |                                          |
 |                                          V
 |     arr.pop(0)                    [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
 |     
 |     for i in arr                  [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
 |                                             ^
 |_____________________________________________|
 |_____________________________________________|
 |                                             |
 |                                             V
 |     arr.pop(0)                    [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9] 
 |     
 |     for i in arr                  [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
 |                                                ^
 |________________________________________________|
 |________________________________________________|
 |                                                |
 |                                                V
 |     arr.pop(0)                    [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Answer (score 4):

It is not recommended to modify the sequence(or mapping) while you iterate it. It will mess interal pointer.

For example, following code will never end.

```
arr = [1,2,3]
for i in arr:
    print i
    arr.append(i)
```

According to [`for` statement - NOTE](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-for-statement):

> **Note:** There is a subtlety when the sequence is being modified by the
>   loop (this can only occur for mutable sequences, i.e. lists). An
>   internal counter is used to keep track of which item is used next, and
>   this is incremented on each iteration. When this counter has reached
>   the length of the sequence the loop terminates. **This means that if the
>   suite deletes the current (or a previous) item from the sequence, the
>   next item will be skipped (since it gets the index of the current item
>   which has already been treated).** Likewise, if the suite inserts an
>   item in the sequence before the current item, the current item will be
>   treated again the next time through the loop. This can lead to nasty
>   bugs that can be avoided by making a temporary copy using a slice of
>   the whole sequence, e.g.,
>
> ```
> for x in a[:]:
>    if x < 0: a.remove(x)
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Apparently what you whanted is:

```
for i in range(len(arr)):
    arr.pop(0)
```

Because, as @falsetru mentioned, changing the sequence during the iteration is not recommended, but in this example your for loop is based on a constant value, i.e. the length of `arr`. Each `pop()` will remove the first element and the list will be progressively emptied.

Answer (score 1):

It's easier to see whats going on by adding an enumerate:

```
for index,i in enumerate(arr):
    if i in arr:
        print(index,i)
        arr.pop(0)
print arr
```

outputs:

```
(0, 0)
(1, 2)
(2, 4)
(3, 6)
(4, 8)
[5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Popping changes the length of the array but the index for the iterator isn't updated to reflect this.

Answer (score 1):

Let me show you what happens in the code:

```
# Initial position
 [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
# ^
# i

# Remove first
 [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
# ^
# i

# Move next
 [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
#    ^
#    i

# Remove first
 [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
#    ^
#    i

# Move next
 [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
#       ^
#       i

# And so on...

 [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
#             ^
#             i

# Remove first
 [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
#             ^
#             i

# Move next
# Oops, the end of the list

# The result:

[5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Let's see how does it work under the hood. Firstly, we need an iterator:

```
# for i in arr:

In [30]: it = iter(arr)

In [31]: it
Out[31]: <listiterator at 0x130f9d0>
```

And we will call `next(it)` until it rises a `StopIteration` exception. So, let's do it:

```
In [32]: i = next(it)

In [33]: i
Out[33]: 0
```

Wow, we got the first element from the list! Let's see, what will happen if we try to pop element with zero index:

```
# if i in arr:
#     print i
#     arr.pop(0)

In [34]: i in arr
Out[34]: True

In [35]: print i
0

In [36]: arr.pop(0)
Out[36]: 0

In [37]: arr
Out[37]: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Okay, element has popped. Move to next loop iteration:

```
In [38]: i = next(it)

In [39]: i
Out[39]: 2
```

Hmm... Seems right, we got the second element. Let's pop the first again!

```
In [40]: i in arr
Out[40]: True

In [41]: print i
2

In [42]: arr.pop(0)
Out[42]: 1

In [43]: arr
Out[43]: [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Let's see at third iteration:

```
In [44]: i = next(it)

In [45]: i
Out[45]: 4
```

I guess, it's clear now, that loop will have 5 iterations. In each iteration you will remove the first element. And, because of it, you will skip odd elements while iterating.